# Spring Security Как отображать все страницы кроме

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, безопасность

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Хочу реализовать отображение всех страниц для не авторизированных пользователей кроме страницы accaunt. Никак не получается, подскажите пожалуйста. Отображает все страницы, а блокировки нет на страницу accaunt.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

//    @Bean
//    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
//        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
//        manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
//        return manager;
//    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("superadmin").password("superadmin").roles("SUPERADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/accaunt").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")  
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", false)
//            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();


    }
}
```

Comment: Поменяйте последовательность фильтров. В начале должны идти более строгие фильтры, а за ними более общие. У вас наоборот.

Comment: @aleshka-batman спасибо большое. Я на стадии изучения, не знал.

Comment: @aleshka-batman добавьте ответ, я помечу как правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FilterSecurityInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/web-app-security.html#core-web-filters)

Паттерны проверяются в том порядке, в котором они объявлены. То есть, если у вас объявлено:

```
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/accaunt").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```

это значит, что первый паттерн будет перекрывать второй, и путь "/accaunt" не будет защищен.
Более специфичные паттерны должны быть объявлены раньше, чем более общие:

```
.antMatchers("/accaunt").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```